# Is it possible to supply a baseURI when using DOMParser.parseFromString?

Tags: javascript

I am using `DOMParser` to parse a document that contains relative URLs for things like the action property of a form. Because the baseURI of the document created by `DOMParser` is `null` accessing the action property yields a blank string. I can get around this by using `getAttribute` but if it is possible to specify a baseURI when using `DOMParser` that would be ideal.

Comment: can you sneak a `<base>` tag into the html you are parsing? (used to work in xsl...)

Comment: @dandavis That works also, but I feel like there should be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: there won't be; the doc context is supposed to be like that, and there's not a lot extra options/config for DOMParsers. you could use `innerHTML` to interpret the urls as from the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than injecting a `<base>` in the HTML before parsing, have you considered doing something similar *after* parsing?

```js
function parse(baseUri, htmlStr) {
    var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');
    var base = doc.createElement('base');
    base.href = baseUri;
    doc.head.appendChild(base);
    return doc;
}

var parsedDoc = parse('http://example.com', '<form action="/index.html"></form>');

console.log(

    parsedDoc.querySelector('form').action

)
```