# How can I parse HTML into a DOM tree, taking into account its origin location?

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

I am writing a user script that runs on `https://example.net` and makes `fetch` requests for HTML documents from `https://example.com` that I want to parse into HTML DOM trees.

The `fetch` API only gives me the raw HTML source.  I can parse it myself using `DOMParser`, but I run into a problem with relative links.  Suppose the document from `https://example.com` contains something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <p> <a href="/foo">hello!</a>
```

If I obtain the DOM node for that `body > p > a` element and read its `href` property, the value I obtain will be `https://example.net/foo`.  This is because `DOMParser` assigns the source location of the ambient document to the parsing result.  I want to assign it the actual source of the document so that relative links resolve correctly.

Right now the only workarounds I can think of are:

- inject a `<base>` element into the DOM tree, which may interfere with a `<base>` tag present in the actual HTML source
- use `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` and then `.write()`, which gives me a document with a blank source location, where relative links are at least not resolved incorrectly (but will not be resolved at all).  Except this doesn't work in a user script: it throws a `SecurityError`.
- use `Proxy` to intercept accesses to the `href` property, which seems too heavyweight to comfortably fit in a user script
- include a userland HTML parser and DOM implementation, which again seems too burdensome

I also realise that parsing HTML from Unicode text obtained by `.text()` will bypass the HTML encoding detection algorithm.  I can live with that myself, because the site I am interested in exclusively uses UTF-8 correctly denoted in headers, but this is also a flaw that should be noted.  Ideally, an HTML document ought to be parsed directly from a `Blob` or even a `ReadableStream`.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Loop over the relevant elements afterwards, and update their `href`/`src` attribute content to the correct absolute URL? (If that remote document you are reading itself contains a `base` element, you would need to use the content of that.)

Comment: Question: if there is already a `<base>` present, would you not just want to do nothing? Seems like all you need is a conditional to handle that case, and you can easily go the `<base>` injecting route.

Comment: Is it about getting the actual absolute URL that the page would have (`https://example.com/foo`), or about getting the actual value of the attribute (`/foo`)?

Comment: I gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57103025/1244884) to a somewhat related question. Might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `fetch`, use `XMLHttpRequest`, which has the [built-in capability to parse HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest#browser_compatibility) into a `Document`.

You have to explicitly request a document by assigning the string `"document"` to the `responseType` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` object after calling `open()` but before calling `send()`.

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = () => {
  console.log(
    Array.from(xhr.responseXML.links).map(({ href }) => href)
  );
}
xhr.open("GET", "https://example.com");
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.send();
```

In my tests relative URLs are converted to absolute URLs based on the source document.

Answer (score 0):

If you can inject the base elements into the DOM tree that would be the easiest approach.
However if think of another potential way, you can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object to construct a new absolute URL based on the base URL of the document. For example-

```
const base = new URL('https://example.com');
const html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p><a href="/foo">hello!</a></p></body></html>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
const link = doc.querySelector('a');
const href = link.href;
const absUrl = new URL(href, base).href;
console.log(absUrl); // output: "https://example.com/foo"
```

In this way, you can assure that relative links are settled correctly without having to insinuate a base element into the DOM tree or use a userland HTML parser and DOM implementation.